# How to disable window.location from a website at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I'm trying to prevent a certain website from being able to use javascript to redirect the browser to another page. The script that is used by website is given below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr.status == 601 || xhr.responseText.indexOf('8ba7aa83-447f-4e1f-b9fa-380e514f2140') > -1) {
            window.location = '/Security/Authentication/UserLogin';
        }
    });
```

The script in question is an inline script. How can I remove that script in browser (Using Greasemonkey or any other technique) before page load so that I can view that page.

I am trying to use GreaseMonkey and Tampermonkey for this task but still no success.

Comment: There's no way because `location` is unforgeable per specification, but you can spoof jQuery.ajaxComplete with your own code.

Comment: Why do you use content security policy ?

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for your reply. As I am newbie to Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey, can you kindly elaborate how can I spoof jQuery.ajaxComplete ? That would be great if you could share complete code snippet.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you please respond?

Comment: Try searching for examples [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hook%7Cspoof+jquery).